# Для каждого тега, вывести к-во постов используя промежуточную таблицу с связью many to many

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Нужно вывести к-во постов для каждого тега с таблицы tags. Инфа о постах храниться в таблице posts_tag с связью mtm. 
Подскажите что не так, я пробовал таким запросом, но что-то через промежуточную таблицу ни как

SELECT count(*) FROM posts, blog_tags, tags WHERE (posts.id = blog_tags.post_id) AND (blog_tags.tag_id = tags.id);

Есть три таблицы
  **posts**

```
 id | title  |body|
 1    'text'  'text'
 2    'text'  'text'
 3    'text'  'text'
 4    'text'  'text'

posts_tag
     | post_id | tag_id |
           1        1
           3        2
           2        1
           1        2
           2        4
           1        3


   tags
         | id | name |
           1      tag1
           2      tag2
           3      tag3
           4      tag4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял, что Вы пытались сделать, учитывая то, что кол-во постов привязанных к определенному тегу равняется кол-ву упоминаний `id` этого тега в таблице `posts_tag`.

Если я все правильно понял то, что Вы хотите сделать, то вот запрос:

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(tag_id) AS sum 
FROM posts_tag GROUP BY tag_id
```

Ну и, собственно, вывод:

```
tag_id  sum
  1      2
  2      2
  3      1
  4      1
```